# How to find a convex decompositions of a given element of a polytope?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Suppose we are given a finite number of points $x_k\in\mathbb R^n$, and we know that $x$ is in the convex hull of these points.

Is there a procedure or algorithm to find a set of coefficients $p_k\ge0$ such that $x=\sum_k p_k x_k$ and $\sum_k p_k=1$?

I'm aware of [a related question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/11508/84108) asking about how to solve the associated membership problem. The answers there suggest that a possible solution comes from linear programming, but I don't know if this is still the case if we are looking for the coefficients, not just to solve membership.
Also, as I'm not well-versed with linear programming, I was hoping for some more detail on how that approach would actually work (if linear programming is indeed what's needed to find the coefficients).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use linear programming to find such $p_k$.  For each $k$, let $p_k$ be the desired weight.  The objective is arbitrary, so you can minimize the constant $0$ function.  The (linear) constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_k x^k_i p_k &= x_i &&\text{for $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \\
\sum_k p_k &= 1 \\
0 \le p_k &\le 1 &&\text{for all $k$}\\
\end{align}

Comment: My naive understanding of linear programming is that it's about maximising a linear target function subject to linear constraints. If the target function is constant, how am I getting anything useful out of it? Isn't the solution trivially the whole feasible region? Unless you mean that by using a constant function the LP problem becomes equivalent to that of characterising the feasible region itself. But then how would you apply e.g. the simplex algorithm to solve the problem, when such algorithms rely on moving towards regions that increase the value of the target function?

Comment: Yes, LP optimizes a linear objective function subject to linear constraints.  If the objective function is constant, an LP solver will return any feasible solution (a single point in the feasible region), which is exactly what you want.  The simplex algorithm typically performs two phases: phase 1 introduces an artificial objective function that minimizes infeasibility, and phase 2 improves the resulting feasible solution to an optimal one.  Here, we need only phase 1.

Comment: a question: as I understand it, we are essentially saying that the problem of finding the coefficients can be reformulated as the linear problem $X\mathbf p=\mathbf x$, with the $i$-th column of $X$ being $x_i$. The constraint $\sum_i p_i=1$ can then also be embedded into this, with something like $\tilde X\mathbf p=(\mathbf x^T, 1)^T$. Do we then really need a linear programming solver for this? It seems simply approaching it as a linear algebra problem (take pseudo-inverse of $\tilde X$ and translate via its kernel) would suffice here

Comment: You also need nonnegativity of $p$.

Comment: indeed. I was thinking that can be obtained by finding the intersection of $\tilde X^+\tilde{\mathbf x}+\ker(\tilde X)$ (the general solution set) with the positive sector... though I guess finding the intersection of a linear space with the positive cone $x_i\ge0$ again amounts to solving a linear programming task? I'm essentially wondering whether the full machinery of LP needs to be used when we don't actually need to optimise a value function

Comment: see my answer for an example of what I mean

Answer (score 1):

As per [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3804250/173147), linear programming achieves this. The idea is that the problem of finding the coefficients $p_i\ge0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i \mathbf x_i = \mathbf x\in\mathbb R^d$ with $\sum_i p_i=1$ can be reframed as the task of finding the vector $\mathbf p\in\mathbb R^n$ such that
$X\mathbf p = \mathbf x,$
where $X$ is the matrix whose $i$-th *column* is $\mathbf x_i$, under the constraints $\mathbf p\ge0$ and $\sum_i p_i = 1$. This is a linear program in standard form.

Approaching it as a standard linear algebraic task, we can define the quantities
$$
    \tilde X=\begin{pmatrix} X \\ 1 \cdots 1\end{pmatrix}
    \quad\text{ and }\quad
    \tilde{\mathbf x}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf x \\ 1\end{pmatrix},\tag1
$$
to rewrite the problem as $\tilde X\mathbf p =\tilde{\mathbf x}$.
Here, $\tilde X$ is a matrix of dimensions $(d+1)\times n$.
This equation admits solutions *iff* $\tilde{\mathbf x}\in\operatorname{range}(\tilde X)$, in which case the set of solutions has the form
$$\mathbf p \in \tilde X^+\tilde{\mathbf x} + \ker(\tilde X),\tag2$$
with $\tilde X^+$ denoting the pseudo-inverse of $\tilde X$.
For (2) to be an actual solution of our convex problem, we also need $p_i\ge 0$ for all $i$. We then use the shifts allowed by $\ker(\tilde X)$ to achieve this.

---

As a concrete example of this method in action, consider in $\mathbb R^2$ the points
$$
\mathbf x_1 = (1, 1),
\qquad \mathbf x_2 = (-1, 1),
\qquad \mathbf x_3 = (-1, -1),
\qquad \mathbf x_4 = (1, -1),$$
that is, the vertices of a square around the origin. Suppose we then have $\mathbf x=(0.5, 0.8)$, and wish to find the convex decomposition of $\mathbf x$ in terms of $\mathbf x_i$. We start by computing $\tilde X$ and $\tilde X^+$, which read
$$
\tilde X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\qquad
\tilde X^+ = \frac14\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Applying $\tilde X^+$ to $\tilde{\mathbf x}$ we get
$\tilde X^+ \tilde{\mathbf x}=(0.575, 0.325, -0.075, 0.175)^T$.
One element of this vector is negative, which means that this is not a valid convex combination. We then consider the one-dimensional space obtained translating this point with the kernel of $\tilde X$.
This is one-dimensional in this case: $\ker(\tilde X)=\mathbb R (-1, 1, -1, 1)^T$. The full set of solutions is therefore
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0.575 \\ 0.325 \\ -0.075 \\ 0.175\end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \qquad t\in\mathbb R.$$
We can easily find that all the elements are positive for
$t\in[-0.175, -0.075]$, which gives us the set of viable convex decompositions of $\mathbf x$.

Here's a visualisation of the set of solutions found with this technique:

$\hspace{100pt}$[image]

Of course, the complexity of this naive approach might scale badly with the number of points and dimension, so for the general case optimised linear programming algorithms will perform much better.

---

A slightly more complex variation of the above is obtained asking to decompose $\mathbf x$ using *five* different vertices. In this case the kernel of $\tilde X$ is two-dimensional, and thus there is a two-dimensional convex region of possible coefficients. We can visualise this situation as follows:

$\hspace{100pt}$[image]

where the figure on the left is used to choose a point in $\tilde X^+\tilde{\mathbf x}+\ker(\tilde X)$ such that all elements are positive, and on the right we show the corresponding convex decomposition of the red point in terms of the black ones.

---

The above animation was generated with Mathematica using the following code

```
decoupleOneElement[list_List,index_Integer]:={
    Normal @ SparseArray[index -> 1, Length @ list],
    ReplacePart[list, index -> 0] // # / Total @ # &
};

lineRepresentationConvexComb[coefficients_]:=With[{
        nonzeroIndices = Flatten @ Position[
            coefficients, _?(# !=0 &)
        ]
    },
    Fold[
        Last @ Sow @ decoupleOneElement[#1, #2]&,
        coefficients[[nonzeroIndices]],
        Range[Length @ nonzeroIndices - 1]
    ] // Reap // Last // Last // Map[
        ReplacePart[
            ConstantArray[0, Length @ coefficients],
            Thread @ Rule[nonzeroIndices, #]
        ]&,
        #, {2}
    ]&
];

DynamicModule[{pts, x, XTilde, kernelOfXTilde},
    pts = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}};
    x = {0.5, 0.8};
    XTilde = Append[Transpose@pts, ConstantArray[1, Length@pts]] // Echo[#, "X=", MatrixForm]&;
    kernelOfXTilde = First @ NullSpace @ XTilde // Echo[#,"ker(X)=", MatrixForm]&;
    Manipulate[
        Dot[PseudoInverse @ XTilde, Append[x,1]] + t * kernelOfXTilde // lineRepresentationConvexComb //
        Map[Total[# * pts]&, #, {2}] & // Map @ Line // Deploy @ Graphics[{
                PointSize @ 0.03, Point @ pts,
                {Red, Point @ x},
                #
            },
            Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
            GridLines -> Automatic,
            PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1.2, 1.2}, 2]
        ]&,
        {{t, -0.1}, -0.175, -0.075, 0.001, Appearance->"Labeled"}
    ]
]
```

---

The code to generate the second visualisation is the following:

```
DynamicModule[{
        pts, x, XTilde, kernelOfXTilde, solutionSet, solutionConstraints,
        pointInConstraints = {-0.1, 0.1}, movingPoint = False
    },
    pts = {{1, 1}, {0, 2}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}};
    x = {0.5, 1};
    XTilde = Append[Transpose @ pts, ConstantArray[1, Length @ pts]] // Echo[#, "X=", MatrixForm]&;
    kernelOfXTilde = NullSpace @ XTilde // Echo[#,"ker(X)=", MatrixForm] &;
    solutionSet = Plus[
        Dot[PseudoInverse @ XTilde, Append[x,1]],
        {t1, t2} * kernelOfXTilde // Apply @ Sequence
    ];
    solutionConstraints = And @@ Thread @ GreaterEqual[solutionSet, 0];
    Row @ {
        (* plot constraints on the parameters, and allow to choose point in the feasible region *)
        EventHandler[
            RegionPlot[
                solutionConstraints,
                {t1, -4, 4}, {t2, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 400,
                ImageSize -> 300, FrameLabel->{"t1", "t2"}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None
            ] ~ Show ~ Graphics[{PointSize @ 0.03, Point @ Dynamic @ pointInConstraints}],
            {
                "MouseDown" :> If[
                    Not @ TrueQ @ movingPoint && Norm[pointInConstraints - MousePosition["Graphics"]] <= 0.1,
                    movingPoint = True
                ],
                "MouseUp" :> If[TrueQ @ movingPoint, movingPoint = False],
                "MouseDragged" :> With[{mp = MousePosition["Graphics"]},
                    If[TrueQ @ movingPoint && TrueQ[solutionConstraints /. Thread @ Rule[{t1, t2}, mp]],
                        pointInConstraints = mp
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        (* show convex combination corresponding to the chosen values of t1 and t2 *)
        Dynamic @ Deploy @ Graphics[{
                PointSize @ 0.03, Point @ pts,
                {Red, Point @ x},
                solutionSet /. Thread @ Rule[{t1, t2}, pointInConstraints] //
                lineRepresentationConvexComb //
                Map[Total[# * pts]&, #, {2}] & // Map @ Line
            },
            Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
            GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300,
            PlotRange -> All
        ]
    }
]
```